# Question about running a javascript based robot with Linux

Tags: debian

Hey there amazing people! I run a robot made with Javascript on the Linux box I run most of my services on. The bot itself is (pretty) stable right now, but server encounters some reboots from time to time. How could I build a script in Debian which would check if the bot is running - and if not - start it? I'd like to find a solution which doesn't strain the server a lot and could be made without root access.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solution.

If just reboot are your problem, you can add a crontab entry with `@reboot /usr/bin/... your program`. I may recommend you to add a sleep 60 or so, because such line is called before the entire system is up.

But you may check some supervisor programs, which restart your program when it crash. Or just a crontab, e.g. every 5 minutes that check if your program is on, and eventually it will start it.  Personally I do also a script that every Sunday it will kill my process and create it a new one. This helps to discover early if some libraries broke your program (you should look just one week work, not  guessing if it was an upgrade (which?) or a configuration change you did last two years.  You will find here a lot of questions about these points. You should just check and decide which way you prefer to go.

Comment: Thanks for very helpful points! How could I check if the process is already running? (in my case .js script ran with node)

Comment: You should check other questions (not an expert of node). In general (not node): A- a process write a `name.lock` file inserting own PID. At start program check if there is a lock file, and if there is a program with expected name and such PID. So process is running, else overwrite file (process was killed). B- simple way: using `ps` command; In general: creating daemon is a common task, and so also the checking if program is running. Look around here, and you will find a solution for your language (node), your environment, and OS.